# Netfilter bypass through Firejail

Tags: netfilter, firejail

For isolation, I run Firefox through Xephyr with Openbox. In the Firejail profile, I set `net enp2a1` to isolate the network through network namespaces. But I don’t like that a regular user can override network rules with the `--netfilter=file` option.

Is there a way to limit the ability of any user *(except root)* to change the network filter rules? For example, the value from the `netfilter-default /etc/iptables.iptables.rules` option in `firejail.config` is used, which no one can override in the future. And the firejail.config file can only be changed by the root user.

A `restricted-network yes` does not suit me, because then network isolation will not work *(`net enp2a1`, etc.)*